# Do I need to provide username and password when cloning code from CodeCommit to AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

I am trying to clone some code from CodeCommit to '/tmp' using AWS Lambda, but it raises an error like this:

```
Cloning into '/tmp'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com': No such file or directory
```

and if I use ssh, it raises an error like this:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

I wonder if it means I need to provide username and password when cloning, or I need some more privileges to clone the coode.

I want to find out that whether it is the username problem, or it happens because I made some mistakes.
My lambda function is like this, and I already hava a repository named MyDemo in the same region:

```
import boto3
import os
import subprocess

codecommit = boto3.client('codecommit')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    os.chdir('/tmp')
    try:
        branches = codecommit.list_branches(repositoryName='MyDemo')
        repository = codecommit.get_repository(repositoryName='MyDemo')
        command = "git clone " + repository['repositoryMetadata']['cloneUrlHttp'] + " /tmp"
        subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
        word = subprocess.check_output(["ls"])
        return word
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Comment: Yes you need to provide username/password, or a private SSH key, when accessing the Git repo from AWS Lambda, just like when you access the Git repo via any other means.